# How to generate Allure Report and seeing it without using anywebserver or adding browser flag?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, report, allure

I'm trying to use Allure-framework to generate a report for my Selenium WebDriver tests.
i can generate report and open it using

```
allure generate
allure open
```

[opened with webserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHwr8.png)

but the problem is our 3rd party audit company need to see it offline/statis. but you cannot open allure report by just double click the index.html, it will cause some element not showing like this :
[open with double click index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0iJW.png)

how can i make allure report can be open without any webserver or browser flag so i can just zip it and send it to 3rd party audit? maybe there some option in allure framework or other external tools is fine, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--single-file` argument and it should generate a single `index.html` file. You can then open this `index.html` file by just double clicking it

Example:
`allure generate --single-file`